# How to order the default navigation items on CRM 2011?

Tags: navigation, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am working on CRM 2011 with a new custom entity, not a default form.

I need that the items under the Common section of the Navigation pane be in alphabetical order.

In the edit mode of the form, the items appear fine, however when I open it as a user it adds me more items in the beginning of the list, "Activities" and "Closed Activities"

[image]

The form behind is the user form, and the front form is the edit mode. The highlights items are the ones being included.

How can I order these items if I don't see them in edit mode? Or how can I remove them from the Common section?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide them using Javascript on the form.

Iterate though the Xrm.Page.ui.navigation.items collection, check based on the name and call setVisible(false) on the ones you don't require.

Other than that, for those particular items you could create your custom entity without the ability to have activities at all.

Comment: Agreed, if you don't want activities under this entity, kill off your entity and rebuild it without enabling it to have sub-activities. If you do want them maybe you could move the other items to "Sales" section then re-order the sections so they appear at the top, and leave activities further down.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will be able to achieve this via editing of the sitemap.

Have a read of this article: [Change Form Navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/gg328217.aspx).

> Change the Relative Order of Navigation Items
>
> The Form editor lets you drag navigation items to change the relative
>   order in a navigation group.
>
> In most entity relationships, in the Navigation Pane Item for Primary
>   Entity area, you can change the Display Order value relative to other
>   navigation items. The lower the value, the higher the item will
>   display in the order.
>
> The  (FormXml) element contains a Sequence
>   attribute that you can use to override the display order set in the
>   entity relationship.

Comment: Changing the display order value does not work in this instance (i thought that might be a way to do it and tested, and it does not seem to work). And if it did, it would place both items together since both depend on the "Activity" relationship, so would not be strictly alphabetical.

Comment: O bad luck, don't know then.